# regex & acrobat's preflight check

Tags: regex

Using Adobe Acrobat DC & RegEx on Mac OSX 10.11

I'm setting up a PDF pre-flight workflow, in part of that workflow I am attempting to have spot colour names that do not match with Regex mapped to a specific colour "other", the RegEx I am using is as follows, basically it should ignore Pantone colours and map everything else to "other"
Could someone please tell me if my RegEX is correct or if I have to add something else, I am not very experienced using Regex

```
'[Pp][Aa][Nn][Tt][Oo][Nn][Ee] [0-9]{3}.*'
```

the workflow runs but nothing is changed,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: Thankyou for replying, im very new to RegEx, the workflow is, if there are any colours that are not Pantone, PMS, ie say a colour made up from cmyk, turned to spot and called "Window" or "Keyline OR do not print",  or a myriad of other words then these colours would be mapped to a new colour called "other" in the workflow, then in my rip the colour "other", would be set to not print, the idea is to eliminate this growing list of colours in the do not print part of my rip.